# How do I manage a savings account for various (non-monthly) lump sum costs?

Tags: savings, budget

I already have a savings account with my bank, and save regularly on a monthly basis as part of a budget. However, I often find myself saving for particular items, say a future trip, or next year's dental insurance premium. Since these amounts all appear together as one lump sum in the savings account, it is often difficult to keep track of what's what. Does anyone have any suggestions for managing this more effectively? Thanks!

Comment: Related: http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/4199/checking-savings-accounts-that-have-sub-accounts

Comment: Thanks for this! Subaccounts would be ideal, but my bank doesn't support those. Mvelopes looks promising, however.

Comment: If paying $10/mo for Mvelopes puts you off, it looks like there are a few open source options as well: http://sourceforge.net/search/?q=envelope+budget Seems like all I really needed to learn here was the term "envelope budgeting"; thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In my blog I mentioned [SmartyPig](http://littleadvisor.com/blog/archives/240) once, seems to be exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Agreed, it seems to have this functionality, but it would be my preference to do this with an external utility, and not have to open a new bank account.